# Youtube Player fragments inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, youtube-api

I really need help with this situation. I can't manage to properly create YouTube fragments for each PagerView fragment.

Use case: 
~ Let's say I have a PagerView with x fragments, and I want on each of it(in a part of it actually) to be able to play a different video using YouTube API.

This is my YoutubeFragment class which creates an instance of the player
    public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {
    private RelativeLayout layoutAbove;

```
YouTubePlayer mPlayer;
private static final String TAG = "YoutubeFragment";

private static final String API_KEY = DateUtils.getDeveloperKey();


// YouTube video ID
private static String VIDEO_ID;

private MyPlaybackEventListener myPlaybackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();

public void setVideoID(String id){
    VIDEO_ID = id;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_layout, container, false);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();


    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

            if (!wasRestored) {
                mPlayer = player;
                mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                mPlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(myPlaybackEventListener);
                mPlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            // YouTube error
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }

    });

    return rootView;
}
}
```

And I use this in my adapter for the PagerView, replacing a view

```
if (images.size() == 0) {
            images.addAll(eventData.getVideos());
            youtubeFragment = new YoutubeFragment();
            if (views.getViewPager(R.id.vp_images) != null)
                views.getViewPager(R.id.vp_images).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            youtubeFragment.setVideoID(eventData.getYoutube_id());
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(views.getFrameLayoutid(R.id.youtube_layout), youtubeFragment)
                    //.addToBackStack(null) // added to backstack of supportFragmentManager
                    .commit();
        }
```

I have to mention that I create the PagerView based on a list with items. I manage to create an instance of the video fragment, but only on the clicked item, but even like this, the video is not being played more than 1 sec. I was careful with padding & other views that might be over the player.

Also, on the next page (that is loaded by the PagerView) I can't event see the YouTube fragment.

Here is the XML file of PagerView fragment(at least the important snippet of it)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeProblematicLayout"
    android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/event_image_height"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_images"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/event_image_height"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_1_dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard_10_dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi I have the same issues can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Well, @siva if you are sure this is the case you are in, my problem was solved by using only 1 instance of the video `OUTSIDE` of my viewpager, somehow `over / on top of` my `viewpager`, instead of creating an instance of the video for each page of the `viewpager`. And I will just change the video ID and auto play after.